# Mosfet Rdson inconsistency in datasheet? Or conceptual error?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, fet, rdson

I was checking the datasheet for the Allpower AP2012S and while checking the graphs to determine the Rdson in my point of operation I found what I think might be an inconsistency, however, I wanted to be sure since I'm no expert.

By checking Figure 1 (Vds vs Id), we can see that for an Id current of 5A, the Vds is around 0.28V, that would give us a Rdson = 0.28/5 = 56mR.
[image: Figure 1]

But then, when we check Figure 3 (Id vs Rdson), we can see that for the same Id current of 5A, we get an Rdson of around 14.4mR, much smaller than the previous result.
[image: Figure 3]

The datasheet also states that Rdson < 14mR @Vgs=2.5V, which is consistent with what the figure 3 gives us. So, is this an error in the datasheet? Or am I missing something?

Here's the link to the datasheet: [Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2111101130_ALLPOWER-ShenZhen-Quan-Li-Semiconductor-AP2012S_C2849574.pdf)

Comment: I'd agree: **Figure 1: Output Characteristics** seems inconsistent with other data by more-than-acceptable margin.

Comment: If it matters I would suggest choosing another part with lower gate voltage required to fully open the transistor. I guess that you want something "logic level"

Comment: @0___________ With an RDSon of ~14 mOhm specified at 2.5V this part is very much a logic level FET.  My guess would be that Fig 1 is wrong, as the max specs in the specification table are usually 100% tested in production. (Though I'm not familiar enough with Allpower to be sure.)

Comment: @JohnD mind "if it matters". And this transistor is definitely not very good in <=3.3V logic. Use driver or different part

Comment: @JohnD for me it is the proper logic level one https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb1ic.png

Comment: @0___________ Absolutely, it all depends on "what matters", i.e. system specs etc.

Comment: Similar product from same manufacturer doers not have this inconsistency https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108132230_ALLPOWER-ShenZhen-Quan-Li-Semiconductor-AP2012_C353065.pdf I vote datasheet error! Also looks like some diagrams were copied off another datasheet as low quality jpegs. Can you trust them?